# How to get MS Word table in a word document next to specific heading using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

I am trying to identify specific value under corresponding column in a word table using c#. Tried:
1- If table index is known - get table range as text and iterate over it to reach certain row and column.

Problem is- Table comes under certain heading anywhere in the document. Index is variable, so can't rely on index.

Comment: Your problem statement is NOT CLEAR. Give us an example of how the table is structured and what the specific value could be. Could this value appear anywhere else in the document? Or in any other table? How can the "certain heading" be identified? What have you tried: show us your code, as described in the [help] for asking questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: Apology for incomplete query. Problem was just to find a table under certain heading in a word doc. For example: Table just after heading <Document History>. 
OpenXML sdk helped.

Comment: So you want to: 1) Search for "Document History"; 2) Get the first table following the found search term; 3) Get the cell at the intersection of column x and row y... and get the text in the cell? And do you want to do this using the interop or the Open XML file format?

Answer (score 0):

As Cindy has pointed out, the question in a current form is too broad. I'm not sure how you're reading your documents. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "certain heading", do you know what text will be before the targeted table?

Nevertheless, you could check out the following sample, the code uses [GemBox.Document](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document):

```
string cellValue = null;

string headingText = "My Heading Text";
int rowIndex = 0;
int columnIndex = 0;

// Load Word document.
DocumentModel document = DocumentModel.Load("Sample.docx");

// Iterate through all paragraphs.
foreach (Paragraph paragraph in document.GetChildElements(true, ElementType.Paragraph))
{
    // Check that paragraph is of heading style.
    ParagraphStyle style = paragraph.ParagraphFormat.Style;
    if (style == null || !style.Name.Contains("heading"))
        continue;

    // Check that heading paragraph contains our text.
    if (!paragraph.Content.ToString().Contains(headingText))
        continue;

    // Get first table after the heading paragraph.
    Table table = new ContentRange(paragraph.Content.End, document.Content.End)
        .GetChildElements(ElementType.Table)
        .Cast<Table>()
        .First();

    // Get cell value.
    cellValue = table.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnIndex].Content.ToString();
    break;
}

Console.WriteLine(cellValue);
```